# Using more than 10 thread consumers with an async producer causes the 10th consumer to hog queue

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to implement what seems to be a standard single producer -- multiple consumers pattern with a queue. I work with `aiohttp` so my producer is async but a library I need to use for consuming is sync so I run consumers in a thread executor and use the `janus` library for a queue that supports both async and sync interfaces. My minimal example is:

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep
from janus import Queue


async def test_concurrency():
    iterations = 10 # or 10k, or 1M

    async def produce_data(q):
        nonlocal iterations
        print('starting producing')
        for raw_data in range(iterations):
            await q.put(raw_data)
        print('finishing feeding data')
        return None

    def consume_data(q, i):
        print(f"{i} init")
        print(f"{i} start")
        try:
            for datapoint in iter(q.get, None):
                print(f"{i} cycle start")
                # Do some work
                sleep(1)
                q.task_done()
                print(f"{i} consumed")
                print(f"{i} cycle end")
        except Exception as e:
            print('error is:')
            print(e)
            print('consumer exiting on error')
            raise
        print(f"{i} producer exit")

    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    q = Queue(30)
    producer = asyncio.create_task(produce_data(q.async_q))
    consumers = [
        loop.run_in_executor(None, consume_data, q.sync_q, x) for x in range(30)
    ]

    await asyncio.wait({producer})
    print('---- done producing')
    for _ in consumers:
        await q.async_q.put(None)
    await asyncio.wait({*consumers})
    for c in consumers:
        print('canceling')
        c.cancel()

    print('---- done consuming')


def main():
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test_concurrency())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As long as the range(..) parameter in the consumers creation stays below 11 everything works as expected:

```
0 init
0 start
1 init
...
starting producing
8 init
8 start
finishing feeding data
---- done producing
8 cycle start
0 cycle start
...
1 consumed
1 cycle end
1 cycle start
2 consumed
2 cycle end
...
canceling
canceling
...
---- done consuming
```

As soon as I use more than 10 consumers (like 30 in the example code), there are no errors thrown but the execution seems to persistenly happen exclusively in the i=9 consumer:

```
0 start
1 init
1 start
...
starting producing
finishing feeding data
---- done producing
9 init
9 start
9 cycle start
9 consumed
9 cycle end
9 cycle start
9 consumed
9 cycle end
...
29 producer exit
...
2 producer exit
canceling
...
---- done consuming
```

Is there something wrong with my use of async flow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there were two problems here. One is rather obvious: run_in_executor will create a default pool for you and its `max_workers` will be your `cpu_count + 4`, so `range(20)` will never cause all threads to work concurrently.

Another (the 10th thread hogging execution) is more tricky. This:

```
consumers = [loop.run_in_executor(None, consume_data, q.sync_q, x) for x in range(20)]

# in BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor:
            ...
            if executor is None:
                executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
                self._default_executor = executor
```

Causes only one thread to actually consume, while this, while seemingly functionally identical:

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
consumers = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, consume_data, q.sync_q, x) for x in range(20)]
```

Causes 8 threads (whatever the default thread count is) to be active.

The solution to the original answer is to create `ThreadPoolExecutor` explicitly, but I still cannot explain *why a single thread hogs queue* if the default pool is used.